# wasJmsClient not supported in websphere 8.5 liberty profile

Tags: jms, ear, eclipse-kepler, websphere-liberty

I'm having trouble deploying an EAR project on liberty profile locally integrated in eclipse kepler. It comes back with the following error:

```
Application 'App-Name' requires feature wasJmsClient, 
which is not supported by WebSphere Application Server V8.5 liberty profile. 

Reason:
Application 'App-Name' requires feature wasJmsClient, 
which is not supported by WebSphere Application Server V8.5 liberty profile.
```

I've read up on IBM documentation which indicates that you need to add suppport to this feature in your server.xml. I have done this, to no evail.

Comment: What version of Liberty are you using? JMS features were not added until 8.5.5.

Answer (score 8):

The Liberty profile comes distributed as two jar files, a runtime jar, and an optional extended jar. If you want to use JMS you need to also install the extended jar. Based on the information in the question this might be missing. You can download both the runtime and extended jar from [wasdev.net](https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/downloads/websphere-application-server-liberty-profile/).

You can check to see if the wasJmsClient and wasJmsServer features is installed by running
:

> productInfo featureInfo

command found in the wlp/bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. Get wlp-extended jar from this link and install it from command prompt as admin.
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/addons-8.5.5-wlp-extended

Install it just by running the following command from wlp/bin folder:

java -jar wlp-extended.jar

It just prompts for license and its quite interactive.I think its good to go from there. it will install all the webprofile tools.

To recheck that 
you can execute the following command from wlp/bin:

> productInfo featureInfo

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IBM Install Utility** (installUtility) inside serverRoot/bin folder to download the required feature:

```
C:\your\server\path\bin>installUtility install wasJmsClient-2.0
```

then add it to the server.xml

```xml
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```